# Java parse String to Object's List

Tags: java, android, json, string, gson

I have a List of objects `Day`, there are some value like:

```
-id
-name
-List of objects `Meal`
```

`Meal` object has:

```
-id
-meal number
-List of objects `Product`
```

`Product` object has:

```
-id
-name
-cost
```

I send to application List of `Day`, example String for:

```
-two `Days`
-two `Meals` for every `Day`
-three `Products` for every `Meal`
```

looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "firstDayName",
        "meal": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "mealNumber": 0,
                "product": [
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "exampleName1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "exampleName2"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "exampleName3"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "mealNumber": 1,
                "product": [
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "name": "exampleName4"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "name": "exampleName5"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "name": "exampleName6"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "secondDayName",
        "meal": [
            {
                "id": 12,
                "mealNumber": 0,
                "product": [
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "name": "exampleName10"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 15,
                        "name": "exampleName20"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "name": "exampleName30"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "mealNumber": 1,
                "product": [
                    {
                        "id": 18,
                        "name": "exampleName40"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 19,
                        "name": "exampleName50"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 20,
                        "name": "exampleName60"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How is it possible to get the same object structur from this string?
I know that probably one of the ways is to use `Gson` but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Do you know [link](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) it will make needed classes for gson parsing

Comment: The structure of this Json schema is not too complex.  You can try out libraries such as Gson or Jackson, or others.  Or you could build your own JSON library on your own.  There are numerous examples on how to do this.

Comment: @eddiecubed I know that I should try `Gson` but not sure how to do it, I usually use it for object lists and use `@SerializedName()` but it doesn't work for this example. Could you explain it please?

Comment: The duplicate marking on this question has loads of answers for you to read through.  You can also checkout codepath https://guides.codepath.com/android/Leveraging-the-Gson-Library

Comment: To be honest I don't think that this is the same example (I mean duplicate), I need a lists  in lists in 'main' object